# Use JavaScript with UIWebView to retrieve element by ID- SWIFT

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I am using a `UIWebView` to load a webpage that is an article. Once I press a button, I create a struct with the `url`, `title`, and `image`. To access the title, I need to access the webpage's source code and grab the title from a `h1 header` that has the same class ID (class="c-page-title") for every article. Would anyone know how to use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript` or `evaluateJavaScript` function to get the text from the `h1 header`?

Here is some of my code for reference:

Struct:

```
struct Article {

    var url: URL
    var img: URL
    var title: String

    init(url: URL, img: URL, title: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.img = img
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Function that fills the Article struct:

```
    @IBAction func bookmarkArt(_ sender: Any) {

    let articleInst = Article(url: (mainWebView.request?.url)!, img: (mainWebView.request?.url)!, title: "Article Here")
    bookmarks.append(articleInst)
    print("array: \(bookmarks)")

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Bookmark added!", message: "This article was just added to your bookmarks.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // Replace UIAlertActionStyle.Default by UIAlertActionStyle.default
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Awesome, thanks!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
        print("OK")
    }

    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated!! Thanks so much in advance.

Cheers,
Theo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can use `func stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from script: String) -> String?`

```
articleInst.title = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"c-page-title\")[0].innerHtml;")
```

The return value will be the html inside of the first element with the class name of "c-page-title".

However, I think a better approach would be the changing your UIWebView into a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview). This will give your javascript a performance boost, if you are running lots of scripts inside your webView from your iOS code.  I would also change that "c-page-title" from a class, into a ID, and make sure only one exists on a page.  You could then use`func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)` which is much better imo.

So it would look like:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById(\"c-page-title\").innerHtml;") {(response, error) in 
    if (response != nil) { 
        articleInst.title = response as! String
    }
    // error handling
}
```

Also keep in mind that this is using a complete handler, it is async, so you will need to build your logic for that.

Comment: thanks so much!!! i will implement this and see how it works. unfortunately, the website that i am grabbing text from is not mine, so i cannot edit those tags.

Comment: also, could i just do articleInst.title = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript("document.getElementsByClassName(\"c-page-title\")[0].innerHtml;") or do i have to define the function first?

Comment: the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScript()` is part of the UIWebView obj, so you can just use that ^....just just fyi I didn't actually test that code it's kind of pseudocode, so let me know if you any other questions :)

Comment: got it working! had to get the element by class but ill give u the check mark anyway. Thanks a ton!